# C++ assignment operator= without calling destructor on rhs

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I would like to assign an object with a pointer without calling the destructor of the rhs object.
or possibly another solution
so that one can be reminded that free has not been called.
I DO NOT want to copy everything in the pointer
because there can be alot in it.

is there a way to do this
or do I just have to remember to call free()?

```
class Stuff {
 public:
  Stuff(SomeObj *pointer) {
    this->pointer = pointer;
  }
  ~Stuff() {
    if(pointer) {
      cout << "forgott to free pointer" << endl;
      free();
    }
  }
  void free() {
    if(pointer) {
      delete pointer;
      pointer = NULL;
    }
  }
  Stuff& operator=(const Stuff &rhs) {
    if(pointer) {
      cout << "forgot to free before assigning" << endl;
      free();
    }
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  SomeObj *pointer;
}

Stuff getStuff() {
  Stuff stuff(new SomeObj(...));
  return stuff;
}

int main() {
  Stuff stuff = getStuff();
  stuff = getStuff(); // rhs destructor is run destroying pointer
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr (better: just use one of these)

Comment: if c++11 then use move semantic. Else do not return temporary but smart_pointers as DieterLücking pointed out.

Comment: ok, thx. 
shared_ptr looks like it should work 
but getting som other problem im going to assume has something to do with mingw32

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to change your code architecture.

Look at std::unique_ptr<>, that may be useful and help.